# How to get the information of a marker from firebase on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services

Hello I am making an application in android with java, huawei maps and firebase but I have a problem that I cannot solve for days is that when pressing the map marker and showing the data in the TextView it only shows me the last record of my database and not of the marker which I select.

[image]

[image]

```
 public void listarMarcadores(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
            final String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            double lat;
            double lon;
            final String nombre;
            final String tipo;
            final String descripcion;

            lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitud").toString());
            lon = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitud").toString());
            nombre = (String) value.get("nombre_puesto");
            tipo = (String) value.get("tipo_ambulante");
            descripcion = (String) value.get("descripcion");

            LatLng ubicacion = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            Marker mimarker;

            hMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new HuaweiMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                    txtKey.setText(key);
                    txtNombre_puesto.setText(nombre);
                    txtDescripcion.setText(descripcion);
                    txtTipo.setText(tipo);


                    //, txtDireccion, txtHorario

                    mBottomSheetBehavior1.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);


                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
                if (tipo.equals("cevicheria")) {
                    mimarker = hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(ubicacion).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pescado)));

                    mMarkers.put(key, mimarker).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pescado));


                }
                if (tipo.equals("chicharroneria")) {
                    mimarker = hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(ubicacion).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cerdo)));

                    mMarkers.put(key, mimarker).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cerdo));
                    ;

                } else {
                    mimarker = hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(ubicacion));
                    mMarkers.put(key, mimarker);

                }



            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al listar marcadores", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Before you use Huawei Map Kit, did you [integrate the HMS SDK](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/hms-map-integratingthehmssdk) into your Android Studio first? By the way, Map Kit's supported devices are only Huawei devices.

Comment: Shirley yes,I do

Comment: You cannot get markers from google map or huawei map? If you are using huawei map kit to cluster markers, you are advised to use the tool here: https://github.com/billtom20/3rd-maps-utils

Answer (score 0):

You are advised to use [this useful tool](https://github.com/billtom20/3rd-maps-utils), which is based on Google's open-source tool and adapts to the Huawei Map cluster manager. You can integrate the tool to cluster markers.

**Usage:**

1. Open Gradle, click **library**->**Tasks**->**build**->**assemble**.
2. After Run, find 3rd-maps-utils-2.1.0-yyyyMMdd.aar file in library/build/outputs/aar/ path.
3. Copy 3rd-maps-utils-2.1.0-yyyyMMdd.aar file to your own app/libs/ path.
4. Add codes below in project **build.gradle** file.

```
allprojects {
      repositories {
             ...
             flatDir {
                    dirs 'libs'
             }
      }
}
```

5. Add codes below in app build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name: '3rd-maps-utils-2.1.0-yyyyMMdd', ext: 'aar')
    ...
}
```

You can also see this documentation: [Clustering Markers](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/hms-map-drawonthemap#h2-1586915875534). Or refer to the sample code:

```
@Override
   public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap map) {
       hMap = map;
       hMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
           new LatLng(48.893478, 2.334595),10));
       hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.891478, 2.334595)).title("Marker1").clusterable(true));
       hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.892478, 2.334595)).title("Marker2").clusterable(true));
       hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.893478, 2.334595)).title("Marker3").clusterable(true));
       hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.894478, 2.334595)).title("Marker4").clusterable(true));
       hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.895478, 2.334595)).title("Marker5").clusterable(true));
       hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.896478, 2.334595)).title("Marker6").clusterable(true));
       hMap.setMarkersClustering(true);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the setOnMarkerClickListener you set the objects below (I assume they're textviews) with the values you retrieved from Firebase, but they are never updated with the the LatLng object. Additionally the LatLng object is never updated after it is initially set. Please make sure that your data objects are updated appropriately, otherwise it will return the same value every time.

```
txtKey.setText(key);
txtNombre_puesto.setText(nombre);
txtDescripcion.setText(descripcion);
```